# How to replace large python dictionary with a memory efficient data structure?

Tags: python, memory-management, out-of-memory, shared-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation

I use a python dictionary to store key value pairs and the dictionary gets too large(>100GB) and hits a memory limit.

What is a better memory efficient data structure to store key value pairs in python?
E.g. we can use generators to replace lists

Answer (score 2):

You can use sqlitedict which provides key-value interface to SQLite database. About memory usage. SQLite doesn't need your dataset to fit in RAM. By default it caches up to cache_size pages, which is barely 2MB .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that could help: https://github.com/dagnelies/pysos

It keeps only the index in memory and keeps the data on disk.